# Tridion CD API - performance

Tags: content-delivery, 2013

Does anyone have any performance benchmarks for the Tridion Content Delivery API itself?

There are some big sites running Tridion - I'm interested to know if there are any requests/second figures documented that could assist me in sizing hosting requirements.

Comment: I've only seen two mentions [here](http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2010/11/tridion-content-delivery-and-caching.html) and [here](http://www.albertteboekhorst.com/uncategorized/sdl-tridion-dynamic-website-performance/) on CD or DCP performance. Note the dates though. The biggest performance change are the CD API started caching queries (Tridion 2009/2011?) and that the broker database changed to key-value pairs instead of comma delimited values. At least the first would contribute to *improved* performance.

Comment: I think most of the time application caching would (should?) be used around calls for heavy load applications too so it might be hard to say...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are specific metric, as the benchmark would be very dependent upon the implementation and the queries it was performing. Basic single Componenent Presentation requests vs. complex filtered, sorted queries across large datasets.

There are lots of option to outscale the Content Delivery environment to handle high load, geo-location, increased deployment throughput.

Application level caching, CDNs etc can also help in high traffic situations.

Any scaling effort will need to be aware of the application specifics, to determine the best approach

Details on scaling Content Delivery for Tridion 2013 can be found here: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%202013%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-5BE8FEAB-6F0C-4B0C-B327-8A0E68358C58